# Animate effect for background but not content

Tags: html, css, animation, scale

I made a full `width` and `height` for `background` which is animated to slowly `zoom in`. The problem is that whatever I put on this background it will also be zooming in. I tried to make opposite animation to even out the effect but it's not very clean solution. Do you know any good way to only animate background?

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-text">
        <h1>Welcome to the Milky Way</h1>
    </div>
</header>

*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;

html, body{
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

.header{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #333;
background:linear-gradient(
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
),url('bg.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
animation-name: bg;

.header-text{
color: white;
animation-name: bg-text;

.header, .header-text{
animation-duration: 60s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

@keyframes bg{
0%{transform: scale(1)}
100%{transform: scale(1.5)}

@keyframes bg-text{
0%{transform: scale(1)}
100%{transform: scale(0.666)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so what you'll need to do is use a psuedo element or an immediate child of the header like so:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="header-background"></div>
  <div class="header-text">
    <h1>Welcome to the Milky Way</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

then move the background and animations to `.header-background`

you will also need to give `.header`:

```
position: relative;
```

and `.header-background`:

```
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 0;
```

and `.header-text`:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

so header-background fills the whole background and is behind the content.

**Note:** `z-index` is only taken in to account if a `position` other than `static` is specified

Comment: @MateuszJuruś awesome :)